# raise RuntimeError( RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

its my installed_apps

from pathlib import Path
from . import config
import django
django.setup()
import os
BASE_DIR = Path(**file**).resolve().parent.parent

## SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!

SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-3hs(_o73c=i#c!s(m4yr@c)4k-3=&381r(y6+qy(8b=4p1@l)l'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

## Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'rest_framework_simplejwt',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework',
'corsheaders',
'users',
'posts',
'settings',
]

File "/Users/macbook_air/Desktop/ReactRoute/users/models.py", line 2, in 
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser,Group,Permission
File "/Users/macbook_air/Desktop/ReactRoute/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 5, in 
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
File "/Users/macbook_air/Desktop/ReactRoute/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 139, in 
class ContentType(models.Model):
File "/Users/macbook_air/Desktop/ReactRoute/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 134, in **new**
raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.